# Rails using aes gem with file encryption/decryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption, aes

I have user and attachment models.I want to encrypt the file, using aes algorithm , with the key when I donwload the file. I don't want to change the file, I want to create a new file, download it then remove from the folder it has been. How can I write the download method.

> attachment model

```
t.string :name 
t.attachment :file
t.belongs_to :user
```

> user model

```
t.string :name
t.string :key
```

> download method without encryption

```
def download
 item = Attachment.find(params[:id])
 send_file item.file.path, filename: item.name , type: item.file_content_type  , disposition: 'attachment'  
end
```

end